# Even though I added my SSL certificate, I get the "not secure" error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl

I programmed a rest API, purchased an SSL certificate with Java Spring Boot, and configured the SSL certificate into my project. I successfully started the project with https, but when I run it from the browser to test it, I get the Not Secure error. But my endpoints are working successfully

I started it up with the domain I specified during the SSL certificate installation, I thought that was why I was getting the error when I ran restapi locally.

Comment: It could be that your browser does not trust the Root CA which has signed your certificate. Just check who signed the certificate and if you think it is trust worty you can add the Root Ca manually to your browser.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.